# Dynamically add imported function call to onclick

Tags: javascript, zendesk-app

I have a script that loads information and uses it to add an onclick call to links. I think it will be clearer with an example:

Script.js

```
const app = {

   init: function() {
     ...
     var link = document.createElement("a");
     link.setAttribute("onclick", "goToTicket(" + data.tickets[i].id +');');
     link.setAttribute("href", "javascript:void(0);");
     link.innerHTML = "Ticket " + data.tickets[i].id;
     cell1.appendChild(link);
   },

    ...

    goToTicket: function(ticketId){
       //Some code
    },
}
```

Sidebar.js

```
import app from './script.js';
...
```

iframe.html

```
...
<script type="module" src="lib/javascripts/ticket_sidebar.js"></script>
...
```

When I click on the link generated in the code, I get an error

> TypeError: app.goToTicket is not a function
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

I've tried different things like adding the goToTicket directly in Sidebar.js but I can get it to run.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Thanks,

Comment: first I want to say try to be consistent with your quotes, you use double quotes (") at the beginning and single  (') at the end. Also I've had this error before and it means that is missing the 'app' in which you declared your function. It will probably wok if you construct your gototicket function out of the app const

Comment: Thanks for the advice you are completely right about quotes. I tried putting it outside the 'app' with export function but had same issue. Ended up using jQuery

Comment: No problem, good to hear that you solved the problem. One last question might it be in some of your other code that you had an ID set to goToTicket? cause this might also throw that error if you have an ID with the same name as a function. Cause it seems weird to me that just doing the same with Jquery solves the problem :p

Comment: There was no other reference to goToTicket in all the code and barely changed anything else in the code to add this. I also find it strange but haven't been figured out any reason for it to work now although it is always possible that I ended up making a change while adding jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually ended up using jQuery. Here is how script.js looks now:

Script.js

```
const app = {

   init: function() {
     ...
     var link = document.createElement("a");
     link.setAttribute("href", "javascript:void(0);");
     link.innerHTML = "Ticket " + data.tickets[i].id;
     link.className = "ticket " +  data.tickets[i].id;
     $(document).on("click",".ticket."+data.tickets[i].id, data.tickets[i].id,app.goToTicket);
     cell1.appendChild(link);
   },

    ...

    goToTicket: function(ticketId){
       //Some code using ticketId.data
    },
}
```

The function is called correctly when I click the links

Answer (score 0):

you can try add module.exports = app; bottom file Script.js

Comment: That seems to be for Node JS if I'm not mistaken. I'm using jQuery (sorry, should have specified). However, I think I got a solution. Will add it here